# How to find all documents created by third party application?

Tags: google-drive-api

In my Google Drive, how do I find all documents created by one of third party applications available on Google Chrome Webstore, or Google Marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the files based on Apps, In Settings > Manage Apps check the box of app which you wish to show.